# Can't launch DataLab on Google DataProc after a while

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

I created a cluster on DataProc with Datalab installed. I used the following commands to access to dataLab:

```
export ZONE=us-central1-b;export CLUSTER_NAME=test;

gcloud compute ssh ${CLUSTER_NAME}-m --zone=${ZONE} --ssh-flag='-D 10001' --ssh-flag='-N' --ssh-flag='-n'

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome \
"http://${CLUSTER_NAME}-m:8080" \
--proxy-server='socks5://localhost:10001' \
--host-resolver-rules='MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost' \
--user-data-dir='/tmp'
```

And it works for a while. I didn't change anything at all, but after like 2-3 hours I ran the same commands above, I can't access to dataLab again, and get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Instance [test-m] in zone [us-central1-b] has not been allocated an external IP address yet. Try rerunning this command later.
```

I tried many times later on and can never success from the first error. This happens to every cluster I created (i.e. not able to access dataLab of the cluster after a while). Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: What was your full command for creating the cluster in the first place?

Comment: And when you say "ran the same commands" do you mean ran the commends to create a *new* cluster, or do you mean you ran the same "gcloud compute ssh" commands against an existing cluster that used to work?

Comment: I mean ran the commands of accessing to dataLab of an existing cluster. I edited the OP to include the command I used to create the cluster.

Comment: If you type `gcloud compute instances describe test-m --zone us-central1-b` do you successfully get the full instance resource config? In particular, is there a `networkInterfaces` field with `accessConfigs` and a `natIP` field?

Comment: Yes I can see the two fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's not just in a narrow window of time at instance startup where the address hasn't been allocated yet, at runtime you shouldn't have to worry about external IP getting deallocated so it's likely a false error.

Usually this occurs erroneously when an instance is in a TERMINATED state. This is in contrast to instances where you configure to not use external IP at all where, you'd otherwise get a message like `Instance [foo] in zone [bar] does not have an external IP address`. This is because in a TERMINATED instance, there is no active VM resource, but the config metadata must still contain a `networkInterface` config to preserve the full configuration metadata of the instance, and the `gcloud compute` logic currently assumes that if `networkInterfaces.accessConfigs` is defined that it is expected to "eventually" have the `natIP` field.

Check to make sure someone didn't click `STOP` on your VM while you were away. Starting the VM back up should get it working again.